# Random Forest significantly outperforms neural net for my regression task. What insight can I extract from this?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest

I'm working on a regression problem for a personal project, and I've noticed that random forest performs significantly better than the current neural net architectures I'm using. (about 0.7 R2 for a fairly deep RF on test-data vs 0.2-3 R2 for 2 hidden layer NN on even the training data). Does this mean that my problem needs a deeper, more complex model? more importantly, since according to my understanding RF uses a random combination of features at every decision node, does this mean I should be trying to extract features by combining some of my features, maybe something similar to self-attention? Or am I deeply misunderstanding my problem? I've considered that perhaps I need a very different loss function, but I think there is some insight i can extract from this large disparity.

For context, I have 15 independent variables as features, in addition to about 500 linear or non-linear combinations of them that I know may have some significance based on papers I have read and domain knowledge.

Comment: Really not understanding the question.  If you are working with a Random Forest model and you are getting decent results, why would you want to go to a NN?

Comment: My guess would be that the NN overfits, it's too complex for the data. Decision Trees and especially Random Forest are much more robust to overfitting in general. Compare the perf of the training set vs test set to check for overfitting.

Comment: @RalphWinters I think you're misunderstanding my question. I'm not so much trying to force a Neural Net, as much as trying to see if it is possible to extract further insight from the very large discrepancy to further improve my model. A random forest and a neural net work very differently, and so my hypothesis was that this big difference could give me some information about the nature of my data, but I lack the theoretical robustness to have anything more than heuristics about what this could mean.

Comment: I'm not an expert on NN. But, the random forest is clear on which variable are important in the model.  I'm not sure if you can extract the important features from the NN.  If so, compare the features from the NN with the RF to see if you can derive which features are missing from the NN.

Comment: The NN could be overfitting as Erwan mentioned, but it could also be underfitting, for example the learning rate is too small for the number of iterations. Definitely check how NN performs on the training set.